# How to transfer Wrapped Sol from one account to another using solana web3.js

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, transactions, transfer

I want to transfer a token from one wallet to another using solana web3.js but am confused on how to. I found this [link](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-spl-tokens) which does go over how SPL tokens are transferred but there are a few missing variables I am not sure about.

```
const transaction = new web3.Transaction().add(
  splToken.Token.createTransferInstruction(
    splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    fromTokenAccount.address,
    toTokenAccount.address,
    account.publicKey,
    [],
    1
  )
);
```

Like here, what is `splToken`, the token program ID, `fromTokenAccount`, and `toTokenAccount`, and what can these values be for Wrapped Sol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of `createTransferInstruction` at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/e651623033fca7997ccd21e55d0f2388473122f9/token/js/src/instructions/transfer.ts#L36:

```
/**
 * Construct a Transfer instruction
 *
 * @param source       Source account
 * @param destination  Destination account
 * @param owner        Owner of the source account
 * @param amount       Number of tokens to transfer
 * @param multiSigners Signing accounts if `owner` is a multisig
 * @param programId    SPL Token program account
 *
 * @return Instruction to add to a transaction
 */
export function createTransferInstruction(
    source: PublicKey,
    destination: PublicKey,
    owner: PublicKey,
    amount: number | bigint,
    multiSigners: (Signer | PublicKey)[] = [],
    programId = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
): TransactionInstruction {
```

You'll notice that the mint isn't included in a normal transfer instruction, so in your case, you'll just need:

```
createTransferInstruction(
    fromTokenAccount.address,
    toTokenAccount.address,
    account.publicKey,
    1,
    [],
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  )
```

If you do any instruction that does require the mint address, like `transferChecked`, you can use the `NATIVE_MINT` of `So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112` defined at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/e651623033fca7997ccd21e55d0f2388473122f9/token/js/src/constants.ts#L13

Edit: based on the cookbook link you provided, you can press "</>" to view the whole source, but here are the specific answers:

- `splToken` is `const splToken = require("@solana/spl-token");`, so you just need to import the spl-token JS library
- The token program id is the account at address `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`, given by `splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID`
- `fromTokenAccount` and `toTokenAccount` are accounts that hold wrapped SOL. Typically, the easiest way to create them is to use the "associated token account" for the native mint mentioned earlier

You can read more about how the token program works at https://spl.solana.com/token#example-wrapping-sol-in-a-token and the associated-token-account program at https://spl.solana.com/associated-token-account

Comment: I am still not sure on how to transfer the WSol from one account to another, if you can read the question again you'll understand what are the things I was missing on.

Comment: Sure, no problem, I tried to clarify your specific questions